# Solving an equation with 1 variable with python

Tags: python, math, sympy

[Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vshm9.png)

```
R = 8.314
AC = 5.457 #ACO2
BC = 1.045e3 #BCO2
DC = -1.157e-5 #DCO2
AH = 3.47 #AH2O
BH = 1.45e3 #BH2O
DH = 0.121e-5 #DH2O
t = symbols('x')
eq1 = Eq(3*R*(AC*(t-298)+BC/2*(t**2-298**2)-DC*(1/t-1/298))+\
     4*R*(AH*(t-298)+BH/2*(t**2-298**2)-DH*(1/t-1/298))-2.044e6,4900)

sol = solve(eq1)
print(sol)
```

I am trying to solve an equation where the sum of the 2 equations shown in the picture `(E15.4A + E15.4B) = 2.044 x 10^6`. So, `t` should be `= 4910`. However, the value I got for `t` from my code was off. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You translated some wrong exponents in the constants (no matter, Koretsky missed one too - B_CO2 = 1.045 x 10^-3). So the constants should be `AC = 5.457`, `BC = 1.045e-3`, `DC = -1.157e5`,`AH = 3.47`, `BH = 1.45e-3`, `DH = 1.21e4`. With @Fahad's suggestion to replace 4900 with 0 in the rhs of the equation, ignoring the imaginary part of 1e-20 magnitude, you'll get the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Making the constant changes suggested, you get 3 solutions (because the expression is consistent with a cubic polynomial in `t`. Evaluation with the `chop=True` option to remove (what I believe to be unavoidable) imaginary parts from the solution shows that your 4910 is one of the solutions:

```py
R = 8.314
AC = 5.457 #ACO2
BC = 1.045e-3 #BCO2
DC = -1.157e5 #DCO2
AH = 3.47 #AH2O
BH = 1.45e-3 #BH2O
DH = 1.21e4 #DH2O
t = symbols('x')
t1 = t - 298
t2 = t**2 - 298**2
t3 = 1/t - 1/298
eq1 = Eq(3*R*(AC*t1+BC/2*t2-DC*t3)+
         4*R*(AH*t1+BH/2*t2-DH*t3), 2.044e6)

>>> [i.n(4,chop=True) for i in solve(eq1)]
[-1.168e+4, 1.166, 4910.0]
```

Because of those imaginary parts, setting an assumption like `positive=True` on `t` will not work -- it will cause no solutions to be returned.